# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present on requested origin" error for res.redirect("http://www.google.com")

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cross-browser, cors

I have a simple task on cross origin domain request.So i created a sample express application that have a route to '/redirect', this will redirect to "http://www.google.com". On front end i created a button that have a onclick event , this will request the '/redirect' .

Code i have on server side:

```js
app.get('/redirect',function(req,res){
  res.redirect("http://www.google.com");
})
```

on front end :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
      app.controller('crtl',function ($scope,$http,$timeout){
        $scope.fun1 = function(){
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/redirect'
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
               // console.log(response.data)
               console.log("got the request for redirect");
            }, function errorCallback(response) {});
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="crtl">
    <center><br/>
      <button ng-click="fun1()" class="btn">Click Me</button>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `res.redirect()` sends the browser a 301 or 302 response and tells the browser to go load `http://www.google.com` which is a different origin.  When the browser tries to do that it runs into a cross origin that it does not have privileges for.  That is working as expected.  The fact that the URL came from a redirect doesn't change anything.  What are you actually trying to accomplish and why is it you think this should work?

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your reply. I want the request to be redirected to other domain .

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your server to enable direct cross domain access to another domain.  The browser simply doesn't work that way.  The browser requires the domain that you are trying to access (www.google.com in your example) to be the one that enables cross domain access.

`res.redirect()` just tells the browser to fetch content from a different source.  If the browser doesn't have the cross origin rights to fetch that content, then `res.redirect()` won't work any better than the browser trying to access it directly.

You could embed the cross origin content in its own iframe and the content could be displayed there, but you wouldn't be allowed access the content from your own Javascript (for the same cross origin reasons).

You could proxy the content from your server which means you could ask your server to get the content for you and your server would fetch it and return it to the browser (via your domain).  This works for some uses, but it depends upon what you're trying to do with the content (something you don't share in your question) whether this would satisfy your needs.

Comment: i tried to redirect the twitter's  (https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate ) from my local machine. And my browser is reporting an error [ api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=0dUdSAAAAAAAxTp-AAABV9iJi3I ]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.2.1.1:1234' is therefore not allowed access.